# Finding maximum value with LinearProgramming command

Tags: finance, homework, mathematical-optimization

So here is a HW problem I was assigned:

> *Thriftem Bank is in the process of devising a loan policy that involves a maximum of $12 million. The following table provides the
>   pertinent data about the available types of loans.
>
> Type of Loan/Interest Rate/Bad-Debt Ratio
>
> Personal/0.14/0.1
>
> Car/0.13/0.07
>
> Home/0.12/0.03
>
> Farm/0.125/0.05
>
> Commercial/0.1/0.02
>
> Bad debts are unrecoverable and produce no interest revenue.
>
> Competition with other financial institutions requires that the bank
>   allocate at least 40% of the funds to farm and commercial loans. To
>   assist the housing industry in the region, home loans must equal at
>   least 50% of the personal, car, and home loans. The bank also has a
>   stated policy of not allowing the overall ratio of bad debts on all
>   loans to exceed 4%.*

Now, I can solve it with the command Maximize

```
(*Constraints*)

constraints = {farm + commercial >= 
 0.4 (personal + auto + farm + commercial + home) &&
home >= personal + auto &&
0.1 personal + 0.07 auto + 0.03 home + 0.05 farm + 
  0.02 commercial <= 
 0.04 (personal + auto + farm + commercial + home) &&
personal + auto + home + farm + commercial <= 12 &&
personal >= 0 &&
home >= 0 &&
auto >= 0 &&
farm >= 0 &&
commercial >= 0};

(*Objective function*)

loanPolicy = 
 Simplify[0.14*0.9 personal + 0.13*0.93 auto + 0.12*0.97 home + 
0.125*0.95 farm + 
0.1*0.98 commercial - (0.1 personal + 0.07 auto + 0.03 home + 
0.05 farm + 0.02 commercial)];

(*Optimal loan strategy*)

Maximize[{loanPolicy, constraints},
 {auto, commercial, farm, home, personal}]
```

And my output is

```
{0.99648, {auto -> 0., commercial -> 4.8, farm -> 0., home -> 7.2, 
personal -> 0.}}
```

But I want to use the command LinearProgramming, but I can't seem to get the hang of it. Here's what I wrote

```
LinearProgramming[{0.0509, 0.078, 0.06875, 0.0864, 0.026},
 {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0.07, 0.02, 0.05, 0.03, 0.1}, {-1, 0, 0, 
   1, -1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}},
 {12, 0.48, 0, -4.8}]
```

^I know the above command finds a vector that minimizes the objective function, but I'm trying to find a vector that will maximize it and I don't how to go about doing so. I tried flipping the values in front of the coefficients but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked if your solution is *the* right solution for the problem, but this is the linear programming equivalent of your program:

```
LinearProgramming[-{0.0509, 0.078, 0.06875, 0.0864, 0.026}, 
                  {{-.4, .6, .6, -.4, -.4},      {-1, 0, 0, 1, -1}, 
                   {-.03, .02, -.01, .01, -.06}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1}},
                  {0, 0, 0, -12}]

(*
 {0., 4.8, 0., 7.2, 0.}
*)
```

I've derived the coefficients by doing:

```
clist = Flatten[List @@@ constraints] /. a__ <= b__ :> b >= a /. a__ >= b__ :> a - b >= 0;
clist1 = clist[[All, 1]] // Expand;
CoefficientArrays[clist1[[;; -6]]] // Normal
(*
{{0., 0., 0., 12.},
{{-0.4, 0.6, 0.6, -0.4, -0.4},     {-1., 0, 0, 1., -1.}, 
{-0.03, 0.02, -0.01, 0.01, -0.06}, {-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.}}}
*)
```